# Display Excel file in the iOS view

Tags: ios

I use the webView display a Excel.
In the Excel file,there are some words,but in the iPad those words is not displayed in the blue box.
I do not know why. The blue box is made of Microsoft Excel.

Comment: Not enough information.  For example what are the words?  How are you displaying an Excel file in a web view?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `QuickLook` framework for generating previews for documents, that can be handled by system (like iWorks or MS Office) - try this rather than `UIWebView`. See more information about this at

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/QuickLook/Reference/QuickLookFrameworkReference_iPhoneOS/_index.html

Failing that there is an open source C library on Source Forge called libxls that you can use to read a .xls file (the older non-XML format). In addition to that, there is a ObjectiveC framework that wraps the C library called DHlibxls. The library will let you read both string and numeric values. The library is quite mature and stable. - you can then render the results yourself!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My English is poor. QuickLook framework is used in my project, but it is not right .In the view there are still some words did not show up.About the Dhlibxls I have already used,it's used for reading the Excel contents.I will try to others.

Comment: Will,I find the answer,that it  changes the a.xlsx to a.xls and it is right!